# $B\otimes_A A'\cong B'?$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $B$ be an $A$-module and $u:A\rightarrow A$ a ring homomorphism. Denote by $A'$ the $A$-module whose underlying group is $A$ and the $A$-module structure is given by $a.x=u(a)x.$ Is there a "simple" expression for $B\otimes_AA'?$ I thought maybe $B\otimes_AA'$ is simply the $A$-module whose underlying subgroup is $B$ and the $A$-module structure is given by $a.b=u(a)b$ but I couldn't prove that. Is that even true?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Different things can happen. For example, let $k$ be a field with a choice of element $a \in k$. Let $A=k[x]$ and consider the composition $u$ of the maps
$$A \longrightarrow k \longrightarrow A$$
where the first map is evaluation at $a$. Choose $B=A/(x)$. Then for $a=0$ we have $B \otimes_A A’ \simeq A$, but for $a \neq 0$ we have $B \otimes_A A’ \simeq 0$.

Geometrically, this is the same as taking a delta sheaf at the origin on $\mathbb{A}^1$, taking its fiber at some point, and then pulling back along the unique map $\mathbb{A}^1 \to pt$.